# using one site's form from another

Tags: javascript, ajax, curl

Currently, I have a site which uses services from a third party.  A link takes me to the third party site where data is entered and processing occurs.  My problem is that the third party site is ugly.  The controls that they use are OK, but the display is terrible.

I would like to use their controls on my page, submit their form, retrieve their output, process it, and display it to my customers in the format that I prefer.

This would be straightforward if XmlHttpRequest worked across domains.

I am trying to decide how I can accomplish my goal.  I am thinking perhaps a CGI script using cURL could act as an intermediary, but I am hoping there is something more straightforward.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing more straightforward. Except for if you're satisfied with their results page, you can just put form on your side and specify `action` attribute pointing to their.

Answer (score 0):

*"I am trying to decide how I can accomplish my goal. I am thinking perhaps a CGI script using cURL could act as an intermediary, but I am hoping there is something more straightforward"*

I think that this might be the only way to do it. That is, a script which will use curl to POST data to the form of the site you mention. Then it's up to you to process the response accordingly.